# Android keyboard - not initializing the shared buffer client because token = -12

Tags: android, methods, input, keyboard, surfaceview

I'm working on a keyboard for Android. I try to use the same popup keyboard style as the popup keyboard introduced by the Gingerbread keyboard. When I run my code on Honeycomb the popups aren't displayed after a while (could be after days of usage) while the popup keyboards are still "functioning". That is although I don't see the popup kb's I can still select keys on them.

When this is going to happen, all I see in logcat is this message:

```
"Surface : Not initializing the shared buffer client because token = -12"
```

This message is displayed every time I want to trigger a popup keyboard. I did some research, even browsed to the sdk source but I can't find a solution of this problem. One of the main reasons is that I can't interpret this warning.

Btw, the same error also is generated by the original Gingerbread keyboard when I run it on Honeycomb (3.01 Xoom)

Any (and I mean any) help is greatly appreciated!